# Nonshared WPF behavior

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, blend, wpf-style

I have two DataGrids on Window and I am using Blend behavior for creating filters in column headers.

```
<DataGrid>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <v:ColumnBehavior/>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <v:ColumnBehavior/>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is, that instance of this behavior is somehow common for both DataGrids, so if you set filter on first DataGrid, it is set automatically in second DataGrid and vice versa. I need to have these filters (behaviors) independent. From what I read it is not possible to achieve with styles.

Behaviour class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.Windows.Interactivity
Imports System.Windows.Markup
Namespace View
  Friend Class ColumnBehavior
    Inherits Behavior(Of DataGrid)
    Protected Overrides Sub OnAttached()
      MyBase.OnAttached()
      AddHandler AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn, AddressOf OnAutoGeneratingColumn
    End Sub
    Protected Sub OnAutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)
      If e.PropertyDescriptor IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim descriptor = DirectCast(e.PropertyDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor)
        Dim customString = DirectCast(descriptor.Attributes(GetType(CustomStringAttribute)), CustomStringAttribute)
        If customString IsNot Nothing Then
          Dim unitType = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(DataGridLengthUnitType), customString.Value), DataGridLengthUnitType)
          e.Column.Width = New DataGridLength(1, unitType)
        End If
        Dim display = DirectCast(descriptor.Attributes(GetType(DisplayAttribute)), DisplayAttribute)
        If display IsNot Nothing Then
          e.Cancel = (Not display.GetAutoGenerateField().GetValueOrDefault(True))
          e.Column.Header = display.GetShortName()
          Dim headerStyle = e.Column.HeaderStyle
          If headerStyle Is Nothing Then headerStyle = New Style(GetType(DataGridColumnHeader))
          headerStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, display.GetDescription()))
          e.Column.HeaderStyle = headerStyle
          If display.GetAutoGenerateFilter().GetValueOrDefault(False) Then
            Dim comboBoxBinding = DirectCast(descriptor.Attributes(GetType(ComboBoxBindingAttribute)), ComboBoxBindingAttribute)
            If comboBoxBinding IsNot Nothing Then
              Dim bindingString = "{{Binding {0}, RelativeSource={{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={{x:Type Window}}}}}}"
              Dim dataTemplateXaml = <DataTemplate>
                                       <Grid>
                                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         <TextBlock
                                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                           Margin="0,0,4,0"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                                         <ComboBox
                                           IsReadOnly="True"
                                           ItemsSource=<%= String.Format(bindingString, comboBoxBinding.ItemsSource) %>
                                           SelectedItem=<%= String.Format(bindingString, comboBoxBinding.SelectedItem) %>
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           SelectedIndex="0"/>
                                       </Grid>
                                     </DataTemplate>
              Dim headerTemplate As DataTemplate
              Using dataTemplateReader As New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataTemplateXaml.ToString()))
                Dim context As New ParserContext
                context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation")
                context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")
                headerTemplate = DirectCast(XamlReader.Load(dataTemplateReader, context), DataTemplate)
              End Using
              e.Column.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate
            End If
          End If
        End If
        Dim displayFormat = DirectCast(descriptor.Attributes(GetType(DisplayFormatAttribute)), DisplayFormatAttribute)
        If displayFormat IsNot Nothing Then
          DirectCast(e.Column, DataGridBoundColumn).Binding.StringFormat = displayFormat.DataFormatString
        End If
      End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDetaching()
      MyBase.OnDetaching()
      RemoveHandler AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn, AddressOf OnAutoGeneratingColumn
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

You use attributes in model to autocreate filters in DataGrid:

```
<Display(ShortName:="Meeting", Description:="Meeting code", AutoGenerateField:=True, AutoGenerateFilter:=True)>
    <ComboBoxBinding("DataContext.MeetingCodes", "DataContext.TasksMeetingCodeFilter")>
    <CustomString("SizeToCells")>
    Public Property TaskMeetingCode As String Implements ITaskView.TaskMeetingCode
```

Comment: Could you post the behavior code please? It's likely that you're using some static values in this behavior.

Comment: I added behavior code. I think there is nothing static.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. There are two instances of behavior class, as it should be, but both instances are bound to same property in viewmodel...